# Environment variables which were defined in bashrc aren't accessible to /bin/bash

Tags: bash, shell, centos, environment-variables

I've defined variables in `/etc/bashrc` in the following matter:

```
export VAR1=yadayada
```

I have bash script called `runner.sh` with the following code below => we run there  another script called `run_test.sh` which is launching a python script. The python script uses the env variable mentioned above.

Here is `runner.sh` content:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /home/john/run_test.sh
```

When launching `runner.sh` from shell I get an error that env variable is not defined.

If I launch the same `runner.sh` from crontab, with having the env variable defined also in the crontab everything goes right.

Can you please explain why from shell run we are not "collecting" the env variable from `bashrc`, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: `source /etc/bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

After you edit the /etc/bashrc (btw what version of Linux are you using?   I usually put stuff like this into ~/.bashrc myself), try running the following command

```
source /etc/bashrc
```

and then run your runner.sh script..

now run the

```
set
```

command to see if the environment variable is displayed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same what you are doing, it works fine on my system. How are you trying to reach to the environment variables using python? Make sure that pyhton is using the os.environ method.

check the environment variables first

```
[john@tilki ~]$ grep VAR /etc/bashrc
export VAR1=bla
[john@tilki ~]$ env | grep VAR
VAR1=bla
```

contents of the scripts

```
[john@tilki ~]$ cat runner.sh
#! /bin/bash

echo $VAR1

python  print_var.py
[john@tilki ~]$ cat print_var.py
import os

print os.environ['VAR1']
```

run the runner.sh script

```
[john@tilki ~]$ ./runner.sh
bla
bla
```